# Python Machine Learning Classifying Words in Sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, part-of-speech

I want to make an personal assistant using artificial intelligence and machine learging techniques. I am using Python 3.7 and I have an question.

When software starts, first it will ask user's name. I want it to get user's name.

```
in = input('Hey, what is your name?')
#some classifier things
#...
print = input('Nice to meet you ' + in + '!')
```

But I want to know name correctly if user enters an sentence.
Here is an example:

```
Hey, what is your name?
John
Nice to meet you John!
```

But I want to get name even if person enters like this:

```
Hey, what is your name?
It's John.
Nice to meet you John!
```

But I couldn't understand how can I just get the user's name. I think I should classify the words in sentence but I don't know. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Spacy name entity recognition](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities) toolkit. It recognizes various entities including Person, Country, Organization and ...

Following code is a working example of how you can use it:

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

doc = nlp('Its John and he is working at Google')
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

Output:

```
[('John', 'PERSON'), ('Google', 'ORG')]
```

**Note**: You may also need to download the Spacy model before running the above script:

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

Comment: I downloaded spacy but it still says No module named spacy

Comment: Here is the colab version of the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Fm2k14Hf3ZdNLI9gOOSQbktN69Pcqpyz

Comment: Thanks. I will try when I get back to home :) . But I think it will work

Comment: Also can I use it for different languages? Because I am from Turkey ;)

Comment: I am not sure about Turkey but you can check it out on their official [website](https://spacy.io).

Comment: There isn't any model for Turkish. What is multilanguage anyway? Can I use multilanguage model for Turkish?

Comment: I get output like this:
`python -m spacy download en
python.exe : No module named spacy`
I also used `pip install spacy` before and it worked.

Comment: I don't get error when i try without `cd C:\Users\acedr\Anaconda3`. I just get when i execute `python -m spacy download en` in Anaconda folder. I executed it in default cmd folder it worked but when i use my python in anaconda it doesn't work ;-;

Comment: ;-; I fixed everything. But I get this now : `OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.` But I get `You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')` Please help ;-;

Comment: @AkınOktayATALAY try to ask your new question in another thread.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! So I need to explain how i got rid of errors i think. So i will start at `python -m spacy download en`. In old times, before anaconda i used normal python. PIP didn't work for me so i did `setx Path "..."`. I set the path to new path. It worked. And I installed spacy from conda and it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get proper nouns. The below code does it:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentence = " It's John"
tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())

propernouns = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NNP']
```

Comment: inp = “It’s John” tagged_sent = pos_tag(inp.split())

Comment: value of `tagged_sent`//as in when you do `print(tagged_sent)`

Comment: The code crashes. It says import nltk nltk.download(‘averaged_perceptron_tagger’)

Comment: yes...so you need to download all these packages...and nltk library!!just google..or write `nltk.download()` and download the required packages

Comment: Sorry but I am at school now. I will try when I get back to home.

Comment: Also can I use it for different languages? Because I am from Turkey ;)

Comment: It worked. I will mark it as worked when i try other answers :)

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I will mark other answer as worked. Because your setup didn't work for "It's". It said NNP to "It's" and the other answer can detect things like person, org or things like that. Sorry ;-;

Comment: No problem!! Always happy to help!! You can always upvote the answer if not accept!! :)